# How to remove that black navigation bar on uiimage pickercontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uipickerview, video-recording

How to remove that black navigation bar on UIimage picker 
we use video mode
already write code for hides the navigation bar and camera controls and toolbar

that  is

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.sourceType = sourceType;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, 1, 1.32 );
```

Try this u can sole the issue

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.sourceType = sourceType;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

Comment: is this help full to you.. or not

Answer (score 0):

as possible you can add this code:

```
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```